# Setting up Commerical SSL Certification for Ubuntu

Tags: ssl

I'm trying to setup a SSL certificate to be used on a test server.  However, I will be having clients connecting.  I went ahead and have paid for the SSL on our domain host.  However they require a 2048 encryption.  When I enter this command

```
openssl req -new -days 365 -nodes rsa:2048 -keyout stage.mytestserver.com.key -out stage.mytestserver.csr
```

I get an error.

> Unknown option at RSA:2048?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -nodes -keyout stage.mytestserver.com.key -out stage.mytestserver.csr
```

`rsa:2048` is actually (or should be) a value for the `-newkey` argument, which was missing from your example.

Comment: Bottom line, he should update his version of Ubuntu no?